# Cardview - Set different background color for each element

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, android-cardview

I'm working on improving my `RecyclerView` and `CardView` skills as I'm new to this.

I created a `CardView` layout and `RecyclerView` layout and then Layout Manager and View adapter, minimum that's required to get the app looking like this -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZzNi.jpg

> What I want to do is - I want different background colors for every
>   element. For example - Red for "Froyo" , Amber "Gingerbread" and so
>   on.

Any way I can do it?

Also, I want elements separated by `1dp`

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do that in RecyclerViews `onBindViewHolder` method by referring to each card by it's position.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position==1)
       holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    else if(position==2)
       holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#amberColorCode")); //and so on..
}
```

here `view` is your `TextView` or any other view which you are using as `RecyclerView` row item.

Comment: Also, can you tell me how to separate elements?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by separate elements? Please update the question with your code and elaborate your point separate elements.

Answer (score 2):

For separating element my 1 density pixel:
Modify your widget.Card View and specify the required space in your relative layout.[Change your widget.card view accordingly]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSJ7W.png

Comment: please write the code using 4 spaces so that it appears here